# Pinch Zoom Becomes Pan Gesture on MapControl

Tags: windows, maps, uwp

I am developing a Windows 10 UWP app. The app has a MapControl:

```xml
<Maps:MapControl x:Name="map" />
```

I add multiple instances of my UserControl XAML control `UserMapIcon.xaml`:

```xml
<UserControl
    x:Class="Taq.Views.UserMapIcon"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Taq.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="20"
    d:DesignWidth="20">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Black"></Ellipse>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

to map by the C# code:

```cs
// ...
var umi = new UserMapIcon();
map.Children.Add(umi);
// ...
```

several times for some purposes. So, you can imagine that there is a map with many circles in it.

The problem is that: my app runs on my touch screen tablet, I want to zoom the map by two finger pinch. However, if one of my finger touches a UserControl and another finger touches the map, the pinch-zoom becomes a pan gesture. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By my experiment, setting UserControl's IsHitTestVisible="False" solves the problem.

```
<UserControl
        x:Class="Taq.Views.UserMapIcon"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="using:Taq.Views"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DesignHeight="20"
        d:DesignWidth="20"
        IsHitTestVisible="False">
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Black"></Ellipse>
        </Grid>
</UserControl>
```